# With HTML, how to know if all the required inputs are not empty so I can enable the submit button?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a form where I need to check for all of the required inputs if are not empty so I can enable the submit button.

```html
<form id="inquiry-component-form" method="post">
   <input id="inquiry-media-outlet" type="text" name="media_outlet" required>
   <input id="inquiry-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required>

   <button id="submit-inquiry-form" disabled type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried to do this with jQuery the problem is that it is not possible because of Liquid/Jekyll code runs at build time. So I need to know a way to do this with HTML.

Any ideas on how can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with *just* HTML, but you can with CSS.

```css
input[type=text]:not(:valid) ~ button[type=submit] {
  pointer-events: none; /* Disables mouse pointer interactions */
  
  /* Styles to make it look like it's disabled */
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<form id="inquiry-component-form" method="post">
  <input id="inquiry-media-outlet" type="text" name="media_outlet" required>
  <input id="inquiry-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required>

  <button id="submit-inquiry-form" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Explanation:

`input[type=text]:not(:valid) ~ button[type=submit]` - Select buttons with type `submit` that are siblings of invalid (`:not(:valid)`) inputs with type `text`.

- [`pointer-events` Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/pointer-events)
- [`:valid` Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/pointer-events)

You'll also have to add `tabindex="-1"` to the button if you want to prevent tabbing-and-entering.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the js is run after the document is loaded? All template engines support JS. It is by no means that you can't use JS to do that.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  const formEle = document.querySelector('#inquiry-component-form')
  const inputEles = formEle.querySelectorAll('input')
  const buttonEle = formEle.querySelector('button')
  formEle.addEventListener('input', e => {
    let filled = Array.prototype.every.call(inputEles, ele => ele.value.length > 0)
    if (filled) {
      buttonEle.removeAttribute('disabled')
    } else {
      buttonEle.setAttribute('disabled', '')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="inquiry-component-form" method="post">
  <input id="inquiry-media-outlet" type="text" name="media_outlet" required>
  <input id="inquiry-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required>
  <button id="submit-inquiry-form" disabled type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```